# How to fix /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js Not found(404)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I read [ngbook2](https://www.ng-book.com/2/). And I try to create hello-world application on angular2.

But I get error 404:

GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js 404 5.460 ms - 58

app.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: `
        <div>
        Hello world
        </div>
        `
})

class HelloWorld {


}

bootstrap(HelloWorld);
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 - Simple Reddit</title>
        <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

         <!-- Stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/vendor/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <script src="resources/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app.js')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <hello-world></hello-world>

    </body>
</html>
```

Look like the problem is in line

But I newbie in angular and have not idea about how can I correct this line.

How can I fix this app?

Answer (score 1):

I have read [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

And I see I must change libraries URLs in index.html to these:

```
<!-- Libraries -->
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```